# How to disable nautilus terminal?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I noticed nautilus is getting slower in navigating when the nautilus terminal is loaded. Is there any way we can disable it in a particular window?

Comment: What do you mean with nautilus terminal?

Comment: Visit this link to know about nautilus terminal - projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that with the <kbd>F4</kbd> key, a user can toggle between terminal visibility options.

Comment: If it has worked for you as such, you can, therefore, accept the answer. Thanks.